# Confused on the logic of my loops in creating variable inside the loop and using them outside the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

My loop is counting how many charts are there present in the page and after that it will store those values of the chart in to variables. I'm trying to utilised those values and appending them into my DOM.

Here's my dilemma, when I fetch the variable inside the loop, eg. visual_pie_val, it will return two values which is "20" and "10". On the other hand, If I fetch it outside the loop it will return the last value only which is "10".

I need it to return their respective value

*Example:*

for **visualization-80**, it needs to return **20** and for for **visualization-81**, it needs to return **10**.

I also need to determine the chart type, so, I used `if` statement for that, if I put the if statement inside the loop, as expected, I can determine the type, but at the same time, I generate the element twice (current number of charts in the page) because it's inside the `for` loop.

**This what my code looks like:**

```
//  CustomVisualizer 

function numAttrs(obj) {
  var count = 0;
  for(var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      ++count;
    }
  }
  return count;
}


var visual = visualizer.charts; // contains "visualization-80" and "visualization-81"
    visual_list = [],
    visual_title = [],
    visual_type = [],
    visual_pie_val = [],

    shadow_box = '<div class="percent"></div><div class="inner"></div> <div class="outer"></div>';


// load key
for(var k in visual) visual_list.push(k);


var visual_target  = '#' + visual_list.join(', #');


for (  i = 0; i < numAttrs(visual); i++ ) {

    visual_title[i] = visual[visual_list[i]].settings.title;
    visual_type = visual[visual_list[i]].type; // currently it's "pie"
    visual_pie_val = visual[visual_list[i]].data[0][1]; // "visualization-80" value is 20, "visualization-81" value is 10

    // remove title
    visual[visual_list[i]].settings.title = '';

    if(visual_type == 'pie') {
        $(visual_target).parent().append(shadow_box);
        $(visual_target).parent().find('.percent').append(visual_pie_val) // visual_pie_val will return "2010"
    } else {
        console.log('not pie');
    }

};

$(visual_target).parent().find('.percent').append(visual_pie_val); // visual_pie_val will return "10"
```

This my fiddle here to better illustrate my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/9hKHJ/1/

I need advise. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on line 14. You put a semi-colon instead of a comma, making the rest of the variables you defined global variables.
 Try changing the semi-colon to a comma and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out although It wasn't the one causing the problem. Line 41 will output two values instead for each target

while line 48 will output one values but it's the last value "10"

Comment: Try logging the value of `visual_pie_val` inside the loop, before it and after and see what comes up.

Comment: I did. I actually commented it out on my code. Inside the loop it will return as 2010 outside the loop it will be 10